# General SOAP Web services questions

Tags: java, web-services, soap

If I have some APIs using SOAP, how do I know if the methods requires a GET, POST or other?

Also, What are the consequence (not even sure it would work) if I use a GET for a SOAP web service requiring a POST? or vice-versa?

Thanks, I'm still trying to get a good understanding on how to consume web services. I got some working with simple API's, but really having problem using a web service that returns is used to download files. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP GET requests generally do not have a content part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367399/260633) which how the SOAP message is transmitted to the server. This is why POST is used.

Specifically from [RFC 2616 Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3). Emphasis mine.

> A message-body MUST NOT be included in a request if the specification
> of the request method (section 5.1.1) does not allow sending an
> entity-body in requests. A server SHOULD read and forward a
> message-body on any request; **if the request method does not include
> defined semantics for an entity-body, then the message-body SHOULD be
> ignored when handling the request.**

**EDIT:**

As of SOAP 1.2 it is possible to use HTTP GET method and get a SOAP response back. I recommend reading the [SOAP 1.2 primer Section 4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part0/#L10309) for details about which HTTP methods are appropriate in what situations.

Comment: Do you mean that all SOAP requests should be POST?

Comment: @ibaralf I updated my response. As of SOAP 1.2 you can use GET for certain types of calls. I recommend reading section 4.1 of the SOAP 1.2 primer (linked near the bottom of my answer).